# PHP inside img src

Tags: php, redirect, image

Trying to see what actions can be performed with a PHP script that is being called via an image src like so:

```
<img src="http://example.com/script.php" />
```

Now, I have tried to include the PHP header() function in script.php:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://example.com");
```

I have also tried to echo an image url expecting the img to display it, which it didn't:

```
<?php
echo 'http://example.com/image.png';
```

Are there any ways of doing such things with a PHP script that is being called in the img src attribute?

Comment: Post the code you have tried.

Comment: An html img tag expects the source to return an image file. If script.php generates an image to stream back as raw image data with the appropriate headers, it will work. what are you returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any ways of doing such things with a PHP script that is being called in the img src attribute?

No. A resource that is used as a `src` for an img tag needs to output image data, nothing else.

There are some  exceptions, eg. a `header("location: ....")` redirect, but the redirect *needs to point to another valid image resource*, not a web site as you show in your example.

Comment: Some older browsers might attempt to execute javascript if you send back some text with the correct headers;  there are some historical vulnerabilities in the sources of images, but I believe they've all been plugged up by now.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `readfile()` as a way to output your image file from your `script.php`

```
readfile($file);
```

Read more about it here in the manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

where Example #1 gives an idea of how to set up the headers.

The manual also states that:

> readfile() will not present any memory issues, even when sending large
>   files, on its own.

and

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function

**ps**: This was the way Wordpress Multisite used to open user uploaded (e.g. images) files.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to use the right headers too? And how will I be able to return its contents to the src attribute?

Comment: yes, Example #1 gives you an idea how you can construct the headers.

Answer (score 1):

Your *script.php* should return the output of an image with the correct headers. For instance:

```
<img src="/html/img/script.php" />
```

*// Script.php*

```
$file = "tiger.jpeg";
$type = "image/jpeg";
header("Content-Type: $type");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind that the src tag should directly point to an image file. However, it is possible to use PHP to create an image, for exmaple by using the GD library:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

So using:

```
<img src="http://example.com/script.php" />
```

is possible, as long as script.php really outputs an image file, for example by using the example as described here:

```
http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-png.php
```

I used this kind of processing in the past to overlay texts on JPG images for a broker website (e.g. new, sold, for rent, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any ways of doing such things with a PHP script that is being called in the img src attribute?

**Yes**, but the PHP Script has to output image data only, as stated in various other answers.

With that being said, just read the image and output it to the stream with [readfile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
readfile($file);
exit();
```

I know I might be a couple years late to really help you, but the accepted answer just isn't true (anymore).

Comment: dont forget the second quote mark on the first line :)

Comment: Whoops, fixed that.